# What's the difference between the different approaches to creating classes from structs?

Tags: ruby, struct

I recently saw 2 approaches how to create a class using structs in Ruby:

```
Customer = Struct.new(:name, :address) do
  # ...
end

class Customer < Struct.new(:name, :address)
  # ...
end
```

What's the difference between these approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby actually has several scopes:

```
# scope one, opened with `module` keyword
module ...
  # scope two, opened with `class` keyword
  class ...
  end
end
```

`module`, `class` some of them.

When you're using the first example you able to share a scope to access the `f` variable, it is very handy in some circumstances:

```
=> f = 1
=> 1
=> Customer = Struct.new(:a) do
=>  puts f
=> end
=> 1
=> #<Customer:0x005561498351f8>
```

With the second example, you can't access `f` variable variable:

```
=> f = 1
=> class Customer < Struct.new(:a)
=>  puts f
=> end
#> NameError: undefined local variable or method `f' for Customer:Class
```

There is also a difference in the ancestors chain - see @AndreyDeineko's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Some difference is in ancestors chain.

First example:

```
Customer.ancestors
#=> [Customer, Struct, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Second example:

```
Customer.ancestors
#=> [Customer, #<Class:0x007ff4328dddc0>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So in first example `Customer`'s superclass is a `Struct` class itself, whereas in second, it's an anonymous class `#<Class:0x007ff4328dddc0>`.

There is also a difference in how the two `Customer`'s have access to variables of the scope of their definition - see @Зеленый's answer.